# java - writing array to a output file

Tags: java, arrays

I am a newbie in java and i need help on my methods.

so i need to create flagOverdueOwners(CarOwner[] inArray) method which generates and returns an array for vehicles whose registration have expired. This is defined as registrations that are over 12 months old based on current REG_MONTH which is 4 and  REG_YEAR which is 2014

so this is my flagOverdueOwners method in RegistrationMethods class:

```
public class RegistrationMethods implements Serializable{

final int REG_MONTH = 4;
final int REG_YEAR = 2014;
public CarOwner[] flagOverdueOwners(CarOwner[] inArray)
{


    // insert code to compare that are earlier than 4/2013

    temp = inArray;



    return temp;}

}
```

and this is in my main method:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
 PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    outputStream = new PrintWriter (new FileOutputStream ("output.txt", true));
    CarOwner arr[] = dmv.flagOverdueOwners(ItStateCopy)
    outputStream.println("\nOwners with Expired Registration");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    {
        outputStream.println(arr[i]);
    }


    outputStream.close();
}
```

my output.txt should conatin:

Owners with Expired Registration

Tasmanian Devil     STU-789     10/2012

Sylvester Cat       NQR-456     1/2013

Yosemite Sam        FGH-123     3/2013

(and there are bunch of lists that are after 4/2013)

ps.this is my CarOwner class:

```
public class CarOwner extends Citizen implements CarOwnerInterface, Serializable, Comparable
{
private String license;
private int month, year;

public CarOwner()
{
    super();
    license = "Not Assigned";
    month = 0;
    year = 0;        
}

public CarOwner(String inFirst, String inLast, String inLicense, int inMonth, int inYear)
{
    super(inFirst, inLast);
    license = inLicense;
    month = inMonth;
    year = inYear;
}

public void setLicense(String inLicense)
{
    license = inLicense;
}

public String getLicense()
{
    return license;
}

public void setMonth(int inMonth)
{
    month = inMonth;
}

public int getMonth()
{
    return month;
}

public void setYear(int inYear)
{
    year = inYear;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    if ((o != null) && (o instanceof CarOwner))
    {
        CarOwner otherOwner = (CarOwner) o;
        if (otherOwner.getYear() > getYear())
            return -1;
        else if (otherOwner.getYear() < getYear())
            return 1;
        else if  (otherOwner.getMonth() > getMonth())
            return -1;
        else if  (otherOwner.getMonth() < getMonth())
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str;

    str = getLastName() +" " + getFirstName() + "\t\t" + license + "\t\t" + month + "/" + year;

    return str;
}
}
```

any idea on how i should code to compare if the date is earlier than 4/2013 ?

any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write serilization and deserilization methods. serilization method will convert all the properties to bytes and deserilization method will use this to construct object.

but, there is much easier method in java. you already implemented Serializable interface to your CarOwner, and use ObjectOutputStream to write it to file, and use ObjectInputStream to read it from file. so

```
 ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream ("output.txt", true));

    CarOwner arr[] dmv.flagOverdueOwners(ItStateCopy)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    {
        outputStream.writeObject(arr[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like "[LCarOwner;@c9bf922" is what you get when you print out an array of `CarOwner` objects.

In this line:

```
outputStream.println(dmv.flagOverdueOwners(ItStateCopy));
```

the `println` method will call `toString` on the array that `dmv.flagOverdueOwners(ItStateCopy)` returns. The default `toString` method of an array produces something like "[LCarOwner;@c9bf922".

If you want it to be formatted nicely, use `Arrays.toString`:

```
outputStream.println(Arrays.toString(dmv.flagOverdueOwners(ItStateCopy)));
```